# How can I convert a .mat file into a pandas dataFrame (via a dictionary)?

Tags: python, pandas, matlab

when I try to convert a .mat file, I encounter the following error:

> ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional

This is the file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sWxsEVX2qa14_UEVLIzeZHE4EmMU0gf9/view?usp=sharing

This is my code:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

        data = scipy.io.loadmat('sp1s_aa.mat')
        df = pd.dataFrame(data=mat)
```

I understand I must convert the file data into a dictionary first, then make it a dataframe but I do not know how to do that.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Import the scipy.io.loadmat module
from scipy.io import loadmat
annots = loadmat('sp1s_aa.mat')
print(annots)
#Parse the .mat file structure
con_list = [[element for element in upperElement] for upperElement in annots['x_train']]
#Use Pandas dataframes to work with the data
import pandas as pd
newData = list(zip(con_list[0], con_list[1]))
columns = ['obj_contour_x', 'obj_contour_y']
df = pd.DataFrame(newData, columns=columns)
print(df)
```

Comment: How would I organize this data into a table? Right now, all the data comes out unformatted.

Comment: Try adding this line instead of print(df)


```from tabulate import tabulate
print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))```

#or
```df.to_dict('split')```

#or

```df.to_dict('index')```